# DOTNETCORECLI@2 Publish succeeds but no artifacts

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, publish, dotnetcorecli

I have a legacy project and want to get into Azure Devops pipelines. I have a build pipeline setup and build seems to succeed. I've added a DotnetcoreCli Publish task and this succeeds but I never have any artifacts available after running so can't implement a Release pipeline.

Wondering if anyone can spot anything daft I've done?

These are the Tasks defined in my pipeline:

> ```
>   - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
>     inputs:
>       command: 'build'
>       projects: '$(solution)'
>       arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
>     displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'
>   - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
>     condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/UAT'))          
>     inputs:
>       command: 'publish'
>       publishWebProjects: true
>       configuration: $(BuildConfiguration)
>       arguments: '--output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) --verbosity detailed'
>       zipAfterPublish: false # We want individual files published, not a zip
> ```

This is the end of the trace of my Publish task:

> (entry point): 2021-09-09T08:57:26.4983992Z        Task "Message"
> 2021-09-09T08:57:26.4984515Z          MYOrg.MyApp.UI ->
> D:\a\1\a\Staging\MYOrg.MyApp.UI\ 2021-09-09T08:57:26.4985051Z
> Done executing task "Message". 2021-09-09T08:57:26.4985655Z
> 1>Done building target "Publish" in project "MYOrg.MyApp.UI.csproj".
> 2021-09-09T08:57:26.4986271Z        Target
> "_InitProjectCapabilityProperties" skipped. Previously built
> successfully. 2021-09-09T08:57:26.4991632Z      1>Target
> "_InitPublishIntermediateOutputPath" in file
> "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\2.0.3\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\build\netstandard1.0\DotNetCLIToolTargets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DotNetCLITool.targets"
> from project "D:\a\1\s\MYOrg.MyApp.UI\MYOrg.MyApp.UI.csproj" (target
> "_AspNetCoreProjectSystemPostPublish" depends on it):
> 2021-09-09T08:57:26.4992847Z        Task "ConvertToAbsolutePath"
> 2021-09-09T08:57:26.4993300Z        Done executing task
> "ConvertToAbsolutePath". 2021-09-09T08:57:26.4993889Z      1>Done
> building target "_InitPublishIntermediateOutputPath" in project
> "MYOrg.MyApp.UI.csproj". 2021-09-09T08:57:26.4994986Z      1>Target
> "_TransformWebConfig" in file
> "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\2.0.3\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\build\netstandard1.0\TransformTargets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.TransformFiles.targets" from project "D:\a\1\s\MYOrg.MyApp.UI\MYOrg.MyApp.UI.csproj" (target
> "_AspNetCoreProjectSystemPostPublish" depends on it):
> 2021-09-09T08:57:26.4996207Z        Using "TransformWebConfig" task
> from assembly
> "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\2.0.3\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\build\netstandard1.0....\tools\netcoreapp1.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.Tasks.dll".
> 2021-09-09T08:57:26.4997005Z        Task "TransformWebConfig"
> 2021-09-09T08:57:26.5010124Z          Configuring the following
> project for use with IIS: 'D:\a\1\a\Staging\MYOrg.MyApp.UI'
> 2021-09-09T08:57:26.5010856Z          Updating web.config at
> 'D:\a\1\a\Staging\MYOrg.MyApp.UI\web.config'
> 2021-09-09T08:57:26.5129541Z          Configuring project completed
> successfully 2021-09-09T08:57:26.5140303Z        Done executing task
> "TransformWebConfig". 2021-09-09T08:57:26.5143720Z      1>Done
> building target "_TransformWebConfig" in project
> "MYOrg.MyApp.UI.csproj". 2021-09-09T08:57:26.5145086Z      1>Target
> "_TransformAppSettings" in file
> "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\2.0.3\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\build\netstandard1.0\TransformTargets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.TransformFiles.targets" from project "D:\a\1\s\MYOrg.MyApp.UI\MYOrg.MyApp.UI.csproj" (target
> "_AspNetCoreProjectSystemPostPublish" depends on it):
> 2021-09-09T08:57:26.5146333Z        Task "TransformAppSettings"
> skipped, due to false condition; ('$(_IsAspNetCoreProject)' == 'true'
> And '$(IsTransformAppSettingsDisabled)' != 'true' And
> @(DestinationConnectionStrings) != '') was evaluated as ('true' ==
> 'true' And '' != 'true' And  != ''). 2021-09-09T08:57:26.5153800Z
> 1>Done building target "_TransformAppSettings" in project
> "MYOrg.MyApp.UI.csproj". 2021-09-09T08:57:26.5156303Z      1>Target
> "_GenerateEFSQLScripts" in file
> "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\2.0.3\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\build\netstandard1.0\TransformTargets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.TransformFiles.targets" from project "D:\a\1\s\MYOrg.MyApp.UI\MYOrg.MyApp.UI.csproj" (target
> "_AspNetCoreProjectSystemPostPublish" depends on it):
> 2021-09-09T08:57:26.5157868Z        Task "GenerateEFSQLScripts"
> skipped, due to false condition; ('$(_IsAspNetCoreProject)' == 'true'
> And '$(IsGenerateEFSQLScriptsDisabled)' != 'true' And @(EfMigrations)
> != '') was evaluated as ('true' == 'true' And '' != 'true' And  !=
> ''). 2021-09-09T08:57:26.5180482Z      1>Done building target
> "_GenerateEFSQLScripts" in project "MYOrg.MyApp.UI.csproj".
> 2021-09-09T08:57:26.5183010Z      1>Target "_GenerateRunCommandFile"
> in file
> "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\2.0.3\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\build\netstandard1.0\TransformTargets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.TransformFiles.targets" from project "D:\a\1\s\MYOrg.MyApp.UI\MYOrg.MyApp.UI.csproj" (target
> "_AspNetCoreProjectSystemPostPublish" depends on it):
> 2021-09-09T08:57:26.5185028Z        Task "GenerateRunCommandFile"
> skipped, due to false condition; ('$(_IsWebJobProject)' == 'true' And
> '$(IsGenerateRunCommandFileDisabled)' != 'true') was evaluated as (''
> == 'true' And '' != 'true'). 2021-09-09T08:57:26.5185862Z      1>Done building target "_GenerateRunCommandFile" in project
> "MYOrg.MyApp.UI.csproj". 2021-09-09T08:57:26.5186601Z        Target
> "_PublishFiles" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(PublishProtocol)'
> != 'FileSystem' And '$(PublishProtocol)' != '') was evaluated as
> ('FileSystem' != 'FileSystem' And 'FileSystem' != '').
> 2021-09-09T08:57:26.5187820Z      1>Target
> "_AspNetCoreProjectSystemPostPublish" in file
> "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\2.0.3\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\build\netstandard1.0\DotNetCLIToolTargets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DotNetCLITool.targets"
> from project "D:\a\1\s\MYOrg.MyApp.UI\MYOrg.MyApp.UI.csproj" (target
> "_DotNetCLIPostPublish" depends on it): 2021-09-09T08:57:26.5188885Z
> 1>Done building target "_AspNetCoreProjectSystemPostPublish" in
> project "MYOrg.MyApp.UI.csproj". 2021-09-09T08:57:26.5189885Z
> 1>Target "AfterPublish" in file
> "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\2.0.3\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\build\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.targets"
> from project "D:\a\1\s\MYOrg.MyApp.UI\MYOrg.MyApp.UI.csproj" (target
> "_DotNetCLIPostPublish" depends on it): 2021-09-09T08:57:26.5190833Z
> 1>Done building target "AfterPublish" in project
> "MYOrg.MyApp.UI.csproj". 2021-09-09T08:57:26.5191798Z      1>Target
> "_DotNetCLIPostPublish" in file
> "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\2.0.3\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\build\netstandard1.0\DotNetCLIToolTargets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DotNetCLITool.targets"
> from project "D:\a\1\s\MYOrg.MyApp.UI\MYOrg.MyApp.UI.csproj" (entry
> point): 2021-09-09T08:57:26.5192771Z      1>Done building target
> "_DotNetCLIPostPublish" in project "MYOrg.MyApp.UI.csproj".
> 2021-09-09T08:57:26.5193415Z      1>Done Building Project
> "D:\a\1\s\MYOrg.MyApp.UI\MYOrg.MyApp.UI.csproj" (Publish target(s)).
> 2021-09-09T08:57:26.5210238Z  2021-09-09T08:57:26.5225190Z Build
> succeeded. 2021-09-09T08:57:26.5260048Z     0 Warning(s)
> 2021-09-09T08:57:26.5260950Z     0 Error(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After dontet publish command you need to make Azure Pipeline artifact.

You can do this in this way:

```
- publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
  artifact: WebApp
```

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) you have documentation about this. After that, you will get an artifact available for release pipeline.

Comment: @PAblo could you consider upvoting my reply if it was helpful for you?